# Unable to define contact points with container names for scyllaDB (using phantom library in scala)

Tags: docker, scala, scylla, phantom-dsl

I'm trying to use scyllaDB container names instead of IP while setting contact points in scala (using phantom library).
Contact Points with IP is working fine:

```
new BooksDatabase(ContactPoints(List("172.30.0.3", "172.30.0.2", "172.30.0.4"))
      .keySpace("books_keyspace"))
```

But Contact Points with container names not working:

```
ContactPoints(List("scyllaDB-node1", "scyllaDB-node2", "scyllaDB-node3"))
      .keySpace("books_keyspace"))
```

Error/Exception:

```
Failed to add contact point: scylla-node1
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to add contact point: scylla-node1

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: scylla-node1: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Here is scyllaDB cluster with 3 nodes:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS          PORTS                                                            NAMES
eea0a5828481   scylladb/scylla:5.1.0   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   19 hours ago   Up 10 minutes   22/tcp, 7000-7001/tcp, 9042/tcp, 9160/tcp, 9180/tcp, 10000/tcp   scyllaDB-node2
5b7a7aa04b53   scylladb/scylla:5.1.0   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   19 hours ago   Up 8 minutes    22/tcp, 7000-7001/tcp, 9042/tcp, 9160/tcp, 9180/tcp, 10000/tcp   scyllaDB-node3
c600ca8258f5   scylladb/scylla:5.1.0   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   19 hours ago   Up 17 minutes   22/tcp, 7000-7001/tcp, 9042/tcp, 9160/tcp, 9180/tcp, 10000/tcp   scyllaDB-node1


Datacenter: DC3
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.30.0.4  1.06 MB    256          ?       2a69bb36-367e-497b-a0a7-9bbd1a9800d0  Rack2
UN  172.30.0.2  1.02 MB    256          ?       8f6dbec5-82bc-40ff-b3d0-a616b63ab319  Rack2
UN  172.30.0.3  1.06 MB    256          ?       921511c2-f9a3-4d11-8db3-2aa8bc739933  Rack2
```

Help me, how can I use container names to make contact points. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the Scala app run in the same network as the Scylla containers? Resolution by name of the container only work if all containers are in the same network.

Comment: No, Scylla Containers and Scala app was not in the same network. Now I made docker-compose file and containers and app are in the same network - and its working fine now. Thank You for your help.